# WebSocket Error during Handshake Unexpected code 200

Tags: java, http, jakarta-ee, websocket, glassfish

I have been using GlassFish 4 as my server.
I am opening a WebSocket connect using this statement:

```
webSocket = new WebSocket(link);
```

Where:

```
link = 'ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/Document/file333B1CDF85-DDDC-E411-8299-F82FA8BE8622';
```

And in the Server File:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value="/file333B1CDF85-DDDC-E411-8299-F82FA8BE8622", encoders = {MessageEncoder.class}, decoders = {MessageDecoder.class})
```

Actually, I have been using URL mapping as well, this "**file333B1CDF85-DDDC-E411-8299-F82FA8BE8622**" is actually is for the user, but at the back end, the control is in the "**main.jsp**" file.
During the execution, the error generated is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/Document/file333B1CDF85-DDDC-E411-8299-F82FA8BE8622' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

**StackTrace** of Exception in the GlassFish server:

```
SEVERE: WebModule[/CollabEdit]Exception starting filter WebSocket filter
java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5909)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Web socket server initialization failed.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.init(TyrusServletFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:131)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Decoder for type: class com.CollabEdit.Message has not been registered.
Decoder for type: class com.CollabEdit.Message has not been registered.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ErrorCollector.composeComprehensiveException(ErrorCollector.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerContainer.start(TyrusServerContainer.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.init(TyrusServletFilter.java:133)
    ... 48 more
```

**Message.java:**

```
package com.CollabEdit;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
 
public class Message {
    private JsonObject json;
 
    public Message(JsonObject json) {
        this.json = json;
    }
 
    public JsonObject getJson() {
        return json;
    }
 
    public void setJson(JsonObject json) {
        this.json = json;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 
        Json.createWriter(writer).write(json);
 
        return writer.toString();
    }
}
```

**MessageDecoder.java:**

```
package com.CollabEdit;

import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.websocket.DecodeException;
import javax.websocket.Decoder;
import javax.websocket.EndpointConfig;
 
/**
 * Decodes a client-sent string into a Message class
 */
public class MessageDecoder implements Decoder.Text<Message>
{
    /**
     * Transform the input string into a Message
     */
    @Override
    public Message decode(String string) throws DecodeException {
        JsonObject json = Json.createReader(new StringReader(string)).readObject();
        return new Message(json);
    }
 
    /**
     * Checks whether the input can be turned into a valid Message object
     * in this case, if we can read it as a Json object, we can.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean willDecode(String string) {
        try {
            Json.createReader(new StringReader(string)).read();
            return true;
        } catch (JsonException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
 
    /**
     * The following two methods are placeholders as we don't need to do anything
     * special for init or destroy.
     */
    @Override
    public void init(EndpointConfig config) {
        System.out.println("init");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("destroy");
    }
 }c
```

Comment: use wireshark / tcpdump to see what is going on. Actually, you can try to hit it with your browser. HTTP 200 is not the status you want to see (you need 101: Switching Protocol, so it seems like the websocket request was processed by something else.

Comment: @PavelBucek okay, there is a glassfish exception at the start of this application: `SEVERE: WebModule[/CollabEdit]Exception starting filter WebSocket filter
java.lang.InstantiationException`

Comment: edit your question and paste the complete exception there. I suspect your @ServerEndpoint annotated class is not public or similar for referenced decoder/encoder ..

Comment: @PavelBucek: its done, please have a look.

Comment: Check if `MessageDecoder` deals with `com.CollabEdit.Message` and is able to be instantiated by container as the exception trace says `Decoder for type: class com.CollabEdit.Message has not been registered.`

Comment: @DonghwanKim: sir I have created a java file named as MessageDecoder.java 
is there any other way to create a Decoder ?

Comment: Well, I don't think so but can you share MessageDecoder.java?

Comment: as Kim already wrote, the issue you have is about Decoder and possibly encoder as well - make sure your Decoder implements one of the subclasses of javax.websocket.Decoder .. so it might look like "public class MessageDecoder implements Decoder.Text<Messate> { ... }

Comment: Please take a look at question I have added MessageDecoder.java

Comment: I'm not sure what is the issue, since the code you provided looks ok. If possible, share the complete (buildable) sources somewhere and I can take a look. (we can continue on users@tyrus.java.net if you want, it might be more convenient..)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue????