# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, websocket, glassfish-4

I am trying to use websockets in my Servlets project.
J2EE ver. :3.1
Server: Glassfish 4.0
But I get an error that says :

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/echo' failed: 
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Also, I get **java.lang.Instantiation** exception when I deploy this on server.

The files that I use as client and server for WebSockets works well when there are only those 2 files in project.
Since I integrated it in my servlets project, it stopped working.So, I doubt it is somewhere because of the workflow we have:

The work flow is as follows in the application:

1. index.html -->This is where the user logs in
2. LoginServlet is called which calls an html create_file.html
3. An html form that asks user to give the file name to be created and choose an extension for it.
   **When this record is inserted in database, a corresponding GUID is generated.**
4. This data goes to a servlet called Collaborate.java .Collaborate.java retrieves this GUID and created a URL "dynamically" using this GUID prepended witH string Document.
5. Once the URL is generated dynamically using this GUID, control is forwarded to a servlet called Document.java(with mapping Document/*) which only forwards the control to main.js.
6. This js file is the client end (has url like http://applicationname/Document/GUID), calls web socket server as follows:

   var websocket = new websocket("ws://localhost:8080/applicationname/echo");
7. websocket server has this annotation:

   @ServerEndpoint("/echo")

What exactly looks wrong in this flow that may give this error ?

Edit: When I deploy this application on server, I get an exception that says :

```
 java.lang.InstantiationException
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:5297)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5909)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2278)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1924)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1762)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Web socket server initialization failed.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.init(TyrusServletFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:131)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Decoder for type: class com.CollabEdit.Message has not been registered.
Decoder for type: class com.CollabEdit.Message has not been registered.
Found Equivalent paths. Added path: '/CollabEdit/echo' is equivalent with '/CollabEdit/echo'.
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.ErrorCollector.composeComprehensiveException(ErrorCollector.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusServerContainer.start(TyrusServerContainer.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.t
```

main.js looks like this:

```
var webSocket;
var messages = [];
var index=-1;
//var link = "ws" + document.URL.substring(4, document.URL.length) ;
var link = "ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/Document/*";
var link3 = "ws://localhost:8080/CollabEdit/echo";
var firstMessage;
var to=[];
var path = document.URL;
var array = path.split("/");
var temp = array[array.length - 1];
var link2 = temp.substring(temp.length - 36, temp.length);

require([ 'dojo/on' ], function(on) {
    cm.on('change', function(arg1, arg2) {
        actionToPerform = arg2.origin;
        console.log("typde dekh: ", typeof actionToPerform);
        lineLocation = arg2.from.line;
        charLocation = arg2.from.ch;
        data = arg2.text;
        console.log("Action: ", actionToPerform, " Data: ", data, " line: ",
                lineLocation, " charLocation: ", charLocation);
        console.log("Location: " + window.location.href);
        var cookie = document.cookie;
        console.log("cookie dekh: ");
        console.log(cookie);
        $.ajax({
            method : "POST",
            url : "../OTServer",
            data : {

                "action" : "'" + actionToPerform + "'",
                "data" : "'" + data + "'",
                "lineLocation" : "'" + lineLocation + "'",
                "charLocation" : "'" + charLocation + "'"
            },
            success: function(data){
                // yup run kr isse :P

                console.log("in success, got this: ",data);
            },
            error: function(data){

           }
        }).done(function(msg) {
            //alert("Response: " + msg);
        });
    });
});


$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    async : false,
    url : "/CollabEdit/GetInfo",
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("data sent successfully: ",data);
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log("Unsuccessful transmission " + data);
    }}).done(
        function(data) {
            firstMessage = {
                "from":data['email']
            }
    });


//this will get the users with whom this file is being shared
$.ajax({
    method : "POST",
    async : false,
    url : "/CollabEdit/DisplaySEmails",
    data: {"url": link2},
    success : function(data) {
        console.log("data sent successfully: ",data);
    },
    error : function(data) {
        console.log("Unsuccessful transmission " + data);
    }}).done(
        function(data) {
            for(var i in data)
               to[i] = data[i];
    });


//calling the openSocket
openSocket(link3);

//console.log("chal gya m chajj naal");
//alert("yaaaaay");
function openSocket(link3){
    // Ensures only one connection is open at a time
    if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
        //writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
        return;
    }
    // Create a new instance of the websocket
    console.log("LINK ISSSSSSSSSSS" + link);

    webSocket = new WebSocket(link3);

    /**
     * Binds functions to the listeners for the websocket.
     */
     //calls onOpen of server when connection is established
    webSocket.onopen = function(event){
        if(event.data === undefined)
            return;
        //alert("onOpen executed");
        writeResponse(event.data);
    };

  //Calls onMessage ofServer when a message is sent
    webSocket.onmessage = function(event){
        writeResponse(event.data);
    };

   ///calls onClose when connection is closed
    webSocket.onclose = function(event){
        messages.innerHTML += "<br/>" + "Connection closed";
    };
}

/**
 * Sends the value of the text input to the server
 */

//Data is to SEND hona h 
function sendText(data){
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    webSocket.send(json);
}

function closeSocket(){
    webSocket.close();
}

///jado response aaega MEANS jab data aaega
function writeResponse(json){

    var response = JSON.parse(json);
    var output = response.data;
```

P.S: I am pretty sure there are no errors in the code. It looks only like a control flow problem to me.
Any help will be deeply appreciated .Please consider asking for details if I missed out anything.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29500133/1803692

Comment: it seems more like a duplicate, since the stacktrace is the same..

Comment: but the error is not the same